# How to call a local ressource from a docker container?

Tags: php, docker, apache2.4

I builded : Apache, Php7.3, and Postgresql images with ‘docker-compose.yml’.

Everything works good, but when I make a call of a local photo, I get a warning message and the photo doesn’t appear.

This is the error message :
****Warning: getimagesize(https://localhost:80/tofs.domain.com/photo.php?id=1): failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address.****

I get the same message when I use ‘file_get_contents’ function with ‘localhost’.

*Note : calling an external ressource works for theses functions.*

I draw your attention that :
I’ve already created a network.
~ All of the containers are sharing the same network (via “docker-compose.yml”). ~

But in my case, I think that the functions used (like : file_get_contents, getimagesize, …etc ) refer to the "localhost/127.0.0."1 of my Host machine, AND not to the network of the container.

So, what must I do to resolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Since `127.0.0.1` in each container means **that container itself**, so you should use `container_name` instead of `localhost`. Run `docker ps` and replace, then try.

Answer (score 0):

With file_get_contents You are fetch the image from PHP container to web server container

```
version: "3.7"
services:      
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    working_dir: /api
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
  
  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    working_dir: /api
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
```

Webserver container needs to have `depends_on` of PHP-FPM container (link betwen from PHP-FPM to webserver should also work).

Now in the PHP container You can do ping `http://webserver` and You should see Your homepage of application.

I don't know why You are trying to do this like this:

- `localhost/127.0.0.1`
- `https://localhost:80/tofs.domain.com/photo.php?id=1`

You can't add domain to the ... domain :)

Your localhost in my example of docker-compose.yml is webserver so this should work:
`https://webserver/photo.php?id=1`

Answer (score 0):

I know, I used "links" instead of "depends_on" to make the match between "php-FPM" and "apache2.4", and it works good.

According to "localhost/127.0.0.1", I meant "localhost" OR "127.0.0.1".
AND
According to "https://localhost:80/tofs.domain.com/photo.php?id=1", => "tofs.domain.com" is a directory for test and not a domain :).

Whene I tried your solution before, the server did not validate the URL, because there is no **SSL certificat**.

I've already created **SSL certificat** for "localhost", not for the name of a service as tested before ...

What must I do ?

Thanks.